# What is the api_site_parameter of stackapps.com in API 2.x

Tags: support, bug

What is the `api_site_parameter` of [`stackapps.com`](https://stackapps.com/) in `API 2.x`? `https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/sites` doesn't list `stackapps`. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just `stackapps`, although you can also pass in the full domain `stackapps.com`.

The `/sites` route does indeed list StackApps, you just need to set an [appropriately large page size](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.1/sites?pagesize=200) (or page accordingly).